# Jquery Slideshow Overlap of Divs

Tags: jquery

My issue is that there is an overlap with this slideshow and I'm not sure why. The first image is pushed down by the second image before it fades out. How would I resolve this issue? I'm new to Jquery so any simplistic help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <div id="slideshow" style="padding-top:10px; content-align:center">
  <div>
    <img src="https://sl.glitter-graphics.net/pub/549/549062c91it46lgr.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://sl.glitter-graphics.net/pub/369/369220a3hjk9pcg9.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://sl.glitter-graphics.net/pub/549/549062c91it46lgr.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://sl.glitter-graphics.net/pub/369/369220a3hjk9pcg9.gif">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://sl.glitter-graphics.net/pub/549/549062c91it46lgr.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)  
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right in your code, just use CSS in this case:

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```